# Очень низкий fps при нормальной видеокарте

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, fps

Я купил на авито компьютер со следующей комплектауюцией:
CРU: Intеl Соrе i3 2100
Видеoкapта: Nvidia GТS 450 на 1gb
Maт. платa: АSUS Р8Р67 LЕ
Опeративнaя память: 4gb DDR3
На нем стоял Windows 10. Утановили ubuntu 20.04. Проблема в следующем: очень низкий fps даже при проигровании видео с youtube. Если взять какое-то окно и подергать по экрану, то станет видно горизонтальные полоски-разрезы, "стыки кадров". При тесте с помощю glxgears на весь экран пишет 40-55 fps, но выглядит так, как будто это 15 fps. Еще был замечен следующий эффект: в местах на экране, где есть резкий переход между чёрным и белым, там где должно максимально использоваться меж-пиксельное сглаживание, присутствует тонкая полоска (шириной в 1 pix) каких-то шумов, снега как-будто. Видно ее очень слабо и жить вообще она не мешает, но, возможно, это свидетельствует о том, что продавец подсунул полу-испорченную видеокарту. Этот шум присутствовал и в Windows. Еще была такая проблема: комп никак не хотел определять реальное разрешение монитора и показывал все в очень низким разрешении, но это решилось изменением дефолтного разрешения в /etc/default/grub на реальное разрешение монитора. Разрешиние: 1280x1024 pix. Были ли проблемы с fps в Windows - не знаю.
Если у вас есть предложения, что такое с fps, напишите, пожалуйста. Или, может быть, это норма для моей видеокарты?

Comment: А драйвер на видеокарту пробовали установить самостоятельно?

Comment: @DenisE, Пробовал менять драйвера, бывшие сразу в additional drivers, некторые не хотели утанавливаться, один установился в замену default-ному, но это ничего не поменяло. Default-ный драйвер, как и реуствновленный - от nvidia.

Comment: https://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=217815.0 - попробуйте для начала

Comment: @DenisE, вопрос по вашей ссылке мне не помог. Репозиторий добавить не удалось (пишет, что нету файла release), да и драйвер nvidia-310 уже удален из того репозитория. Я попробовал потыкать другие драйвера из доступных по умолчанию, и один, единственный open-sourcный, заработал более-менее нормально (видео проигровается нормально, но на его фоне немного тормозит мышка). Но я, зачем-то, стал тыкать дальше, и, в результате, сломал всю систему. Пришлось ее переустановить, я там ещё ничего сделать не успел, так что не жалко было, но при установке не стал ставить галочку "загружать проприетарное по"

Comment: и тот драйвер, который зароботал нормально в прошлый раз установился по умолчанию. Теперь все работает. (в предыдущем комментарии буквы кончались, по этому не дописал)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мое решение: поставить официальный, не проприетарный драйвер, либо переустановить систему без галочки "загружать проприетарное по". После установки все зарабртало как надо, но шум по краям окон как будто только увеличился, но после обновления системных пакетов исчез совсем. Единственное, что сейчас работает странно - при проигровании видео с YouTube во весь экран, мышка чуть заедает, но совсем не критично. Видимо, и в официальном драйвере Ubuntu тоже есть косяки, но лучшего я не нашёл.
Вывод: не используйте проприетарные драйвера, если нет необходимости.